# dependencies issue while doing yum update

Tags: centos6

When i tried to do yum update , got problem, Can you please let me know where is issue?

```
[~]# yum update --skip-broken
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Determining fastest mirrors
base         | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras       | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates      | 3.4 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs-git.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package emacs-git.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: perl-Git- 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 for package: git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64
---> Package git-all.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-all.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch
---> Package git-cvs.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-cvs.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package git-email.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-email.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 for package: git-email-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch
---> Package git-gui.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-gui.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package git-svn.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-svn.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package gitk.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package gitk.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs-git.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: emacs-git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch
---> Package git-cvs.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: git-cvs = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch
---> Package git-gui.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: git-gui = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch
---> Package git-svn.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: git-svn = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch
---> Package gitk.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: gitk = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch

  Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
  emacs-git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
  git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64 from updates
  git-all-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
  git-cvs-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
  git-email-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
  git-gui-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
  git-svn-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
  gitk-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch from updates
```

I tried to manually install those packages but failed, Not sure what to do?

Update:- I am posting yum update output also.

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Determining fastest mirrors
base           | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras             | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates               | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package emacs-git.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package emacs-git.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 for package: git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64
---> Package git-all.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-all.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 for package: git-all-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch
---> Package git-cvs.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-cvs.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package git-email.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-email.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 for package: git-email-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch
---> Package git-gui.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-gui.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package git-svn.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package git-svn.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package gitk.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be updated
---> Package gitk.noarch 0:1.7.1-4.el6_7.1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch (@updates)
       Requires: git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1
       Removing: git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64 (@updates)
           git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1
       Updated By: git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
           git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1
Error: Package: git-all-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch (updates)
       Requires: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1
       Installed: perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch (@updates)
           perl-Git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1
Error: Package: git-email-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.noarch (updates)
       Requires: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1
       Installed: perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch (@updates)
           perl-Git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1
Error: Package: git-1.7.1-4.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: perl-Git = 1.7.1-4.el6_7.1
       Installed: perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch (@updates)
           perl-Git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried so many commands and I found following command very useful.

```
# yum update --disableexcludes=main
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the metadata your system has for the updates repository is out of date.

The update is failing because of not being able to find the corresponding `perl-Git` package update. However, I checked my local CentOS mirror, and the correct update package is there.

Therefore I suspect you have slightly old metadata for the updates repo. I suggest you clean out your metadata and then try the update again.

```
yum clean metadata
```

If it *still* fails, the problem is probably with the mirror, and not your system. In that case, just wait 24 hours so that hopefully the mirror gets back in sync.

Comment: Go find out who runs the mirror site, then, and send them an email. It might not be syncing properly at all.

Comment: If you actually did what I suggested, then it was printed on your screen!

Comment: 24 hours already passed and i tried and failed again, No clues what should I do?